# Is this a failed drive? or am I going crazy? SSD not seen by Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

I have the OS running on a 3 week old inter SSD. The system partition is encrypted with truecrypt. Losing the data is no big deal, since its just the system + programs.

I overclocked the CPU, and after truecrypt wouldn't accept the password. I used their rescue CD, which told me it couldn't read the partition, due to bad sectors. Decrypting the drive didn't work, neither did restoring the headers, or anything else.

In Win7 installation menu, it doesn't see the drive. Connecting the drive as a secondary one, to another PC, causes that PC not to boot into windows at all.

Drive is detected in the BIOS. I tried switching ports on the mobo, no effect.

Comment: I changed the title of your question to make it clearer, and added the SSD and Windows 7 tags.

Comment: Have you removed the overclock since this happened?

Comment: Of course, it did nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that indeed, your drive has failed.  I'd try it in another PC if available, because it's also possible that your *controller* has failed, but if that doesn't work, you'll need to replace it.

Comment: Also try swapping out the _cable_ I have had move cables fail than controllers.

Comment: Tried another cable. Tried in another pc - prevents it from booting, off another drive. This 1 is just connected.

Comment: Your drive has failed, and since you overclocked you probably violated the terms of the warranty.  Sorry.

Comment: I dont see how overclocking the CPU affects the hard drive